# Calculate time different between PM and AM in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate time difference in PM and AM.

I have data of **Monday 1:01 PM and tuesday 1:00AM**.

I used below code to calculate the time difference.

And the result i get is:

**-12 hour and -1 minutes**

How should i go about doing it getting the correct time difference?

Below is the code:

```
if ((dayNow == "Monday") && (tues == "True"))
{
    DateTime timeNow = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), 
        "h:mm tt", new DateTimeFormatInfo());    
    DateTime timeSelected = DateTime.ParseExact(timePicker.ValueString, 
        "h:mm tt", new DateTimeFormatInfo());    
    TimeSpan timeLeft = timeSelected.Subtract(timeNow);

    if (timeSelected > timeNow)
    {
        string hour = timeLeft.Hours.ToString();
        string minute = timeLeft.Minutes.ToString();
        string timeDifference = "This alarm is set for " + "1 day and " 
            + hour + " hour and " + minute + " minutes from now.";
        MessageBox.Show(timeDifference, "Alarm", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/listOfAlarm.xaml?",
            UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else if (timeSelected < timeNow)
    {
        string hour = timeLeft.Hours.ToString();
        string minute = timeLeft.Minutes.ToString();
        string timeDifference = "This alarm is set for " + hour + 
            " hour and " + minute + " minutes from now.";
        MessageBox.Show(timeDifference, "Alarm", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/listOfAlarm.xaml?", 
            UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/listOfAlarm.xaml?", 
            UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Comment: A correct calculation without (-) sign

Answer (score 1):

Bit Late to the show, but here is what I did.

An If statement, that figures out whether the time you have selected is greater than, or less than. If it is less than, then it will automatically add 24 hours to compensate, thus removing the negative sign and compensating for the program.

I converted the times to Integers, and then did this:

```
            if (timeSelected > timeNow)
            {
                int_hour = Convert.ToInt16(hour);  // Convert the string to integer
            }
            else
            {
                int_hour = Convert.ToInt16(hour) + 24;  // Convert the string to integer ( Compensates for Negative)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing:

```
TimeSpan timeLeft = timeSelected.Subtract(timeNow);
```

with

```
TimeSpan timeLeft = timeNow.Substract(timeSelected);
```

fix your problem?